# Is Python cStringIO thread-safe?

Tags: python, thread-safety, stringio

As title say, does Python cStringIO protect their internal structures for multithreading use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at an excellent [work on explaining GIL](http://www.dabeaz.com/GIL/), then note that cStringIO is written purely in C, and its calls don't release GIL.

It means that the running thread won't voluntarily switch during read()/write() (with current virtual machine implementation). (The OS will preempt the thread, however other Python threads won't be able to acquire GIL.)

Taking a look at the source: Python-2.7.1/Modules/cStringIO.c there is no mention about internals protection. When in doubt, look at source :)

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are talking about the CPython implementation of Python.

In CPython there is a global interpreter lock which means that only a single thread of Python code can execute at a time. Code written in C will therefore also be effectively single threaded unless it explicitly releases the global lock.

What that means is that if you have multiple Python threads all using cStringIO simultaneously there won't be any problem as only a single call to a cStringIO method can be active at a time and cStringIO never releases the lock. However if you call it directly from C code which is running outside the locked environment you will have problems. Also if you do anything more complex than just reading or writing you will have issues, e.g. if you start using `seek` as your calls may overlap in unexpected ways.

Also note that some methods such as `writelines` can invoke Python code from inside the method so in that case you might get other output interleaved inside a single call to `writelines`.

That is true for most of the standard Python objects: you can safely use objects from multiple threads as the individual operations won't break, but the order in which things happen won't be defined.

Comment: I don't know if is the CPython implementation, i'm talking about this http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO python object. Is it?

Comment: @Emilio: if you weren't using CPython, you'd probably know it. CPython is the implementation of Python written in C, which is used by nearly everyone using Python.

Comment: I know this is different than the question asked, but you can get around the GIL with C funcs imported via ctypes. http://www.caswenson.com/past/2009/6/13/bypassing_the_python_gil_with_ctypes/ I found it informative :)

Comment: @tMC yes, and that is useful when calling a C function that is nothing to do with Python, but if you call any Python API functions you need to have the GIL locked otherwise very bad things will happen. ('Any' excludes a few special cases such as the function to claim the GIL)

Answer (score 1):

It is as "thread-safe", as file operations can be (which means — not much). The Python implementation you're using has [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock), which will guarantee that each individual file operation on `cStringIO` will not be interrupted by another thread. That does **not** however guarantee, that concurrent file operations from multiple threads won't be interleaved.

Comment: cStringIO does not deal with operating system files at all, so the argument is invalid, even though the conclusions are correct

Comment: @janislaw: who said anything about system files? stringIO exposes file interface, and you perform file operations on it.

Comment: Yes, you're perfectly right. I've mistaken 'file operation' you've mentioned for an implementation -- instead of an interface.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not currently thread safe.